# which plugin will use for bootstrap or html and css like this http://www.gwadarrealestate.pk/map/lahore/dha-lahore-rahbar-map.html

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

which plugin will use for bootstrap or html and CSS like this for zoom

http://www.gwadarrealestate.pk/map/lahore/dha-lahore-rahbar-map.html

Answer (score -2, accepted):

They are using this plugin but it's pay:
https://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-giga-image-viewer-animated-zoom-and-pan/2970559
Free alternative:
http://ignitersworld.com/lab/imageViewer.html

Comment: but this one is totally diffrent

Comment: @AhmedRiaz but it's free ;) Not at all different, you have 2 pictures to specify small and high-res. There are no buttons - but you can create owns and connect with methods

Comment: okay thanks for reply . i will but it.